# Split react render methods into a separate npm package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

We have a frontend application developed in React.
Now we would like to also make a react-native application, but reusing as much as possible from the current app.

I have seen that in these cases react-native-web is often used, however, we have already developed our app with just react and replacing all our current components into react-native-web components would take too much time (also because we are using antd component library).

My idea would be to move all render methods to another npm package (and some other parts that would need a rewrite to use react-native) and import them from the main package.

I imagine a folder structure of something like this:

- root

  - core     -- would contain all the reusable code
  - web      -- would contain all the render methods with antd components
  - native   -- would contain all the render methods with native components

In this way, web and native packages would each have their npm start and build scripts.
How can I, in the core package, and based on the platform (in this case either web or native) import the render portion from the correct package?

I thought I could use lerna library to separate the packages and something like commonjs or requirejs to then dynamically import the correct render element.

**Can you recommend some other tools that can be useful?
Or is the whole approach wrong and there is another way to achieve this?**

In other words, how can we achieve dependency injection from web package to core package?

Imagine, we have a component Home in the core package:

```
class Home extends Component {
..
    render() {
        // somehow import required 'view'
        // example: import('path_to_web_package_from_some_global_variable' + '/HomeRender.js');
        // There would be a HomeRender.js in 'web' package and another one in 'native' package
    }
..
}
```

Comment: *How can I, in the core package, and based on the platform (in this case either web or native) import the render portion from the correct package?* - you preferably shouldn't because this won't allow to tree-shake unused platform. These are platform-specific packages that should depend on `core`, not in the opposite way. Consider providing a short example what these packages are and how they work together.

Comment: @estus What do you mean by tree-shaking unused platform? I want to import only the code that is specific to either 'web' or 'native'. I've added a small sample of how it could look like

Comment: Why not just move the components to a folder accesible by both `web/native` and import them from there?

Comment: *I want to import only the code that is specific to either 'web' or 'native'* - you won't be able to do that. Also, dynamic `import()` is async and it will enforce a component to be async, which isn't a good thing. I'll try to give an answer according to my understanding of how your packages look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Published package is supposed to be conventionally built to ES5, optionally with ES6 exports and imports (ESM build) to use it more efficiently in modular environments.

ES6 imports and exports are static. They cannot be swapped, at least without some module tampering in build tool. While dynamic `import()` is [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) and not a part of ES6. It would prevent efficient tree-shaking, this would result in both `web` and `native` being included into a bundle even if one of them is unused.

Some variation of DI should be used to make `core` renderer-agnostic.

One of the ways is to allow some sort of plugin system in `core`:

```
import { configureRenderer } from '@foo/core';
import * as renderers from '@foo/web';

configureRenderer(renderers);
```

This may work in some cases, but this doesn't play very well with components because this prevents `renderers` from being tree-shaken and restricts `core` to be use either `native` or web`. This results in`web`package bundled entirely, even if only small portion is used. The restriction to`native`or web` may work in this case because platform are mutually exclusive, but it isn't a good design solution in general.

A better way is to implement this in opposite way. `core` has no dependencies and contains common abstractions, while `web` and `native` are concrete implementations. This could be solved with OOP inheritance with class components, and there's a lot of possible to implement DI with functional approach, the one that suits the case is [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) (hence the name):

```
// @foo/core
export class Home extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        const {render, ...props} = this.props;
        return render(props);
    }
}

// @foo/web
import { Home as HomeWithoutRenderer } from '@foo/core';

const rendererHOC = (Comp, renderer) => props => <Comp render={renderer} ...props />;

export const Home = rendererHOC(HomeWithoutRenderer, props => {
  // platform-specific view
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps a lot :)

It is working now, the only thing was to change was the new Home export:
instead of 'export const Home = rendererHoc(..)'
to have 'export const Home = () => rendererHoc(..)'

Comment: Glad it worked. There was a typo, `rendererHOC` was intended as actual HOC, so other props could be passed to it. I updated it.